# How to create a persistent cronjob on an Ubiquiti Edgerouter-X so its still there after a firmware update

Tags: cron, task-scheduler, ubiquiti

We have tens of Ubiquiti Edgerouter-X's on active on customer locations. They among other things responsible for pinging an IP each minute. This is done by a cronjob (set with crontab -e) and works fine as long as the firmware is not updated.

When the firmware is updated to a newer version, the cronjobs are "reset" to the default value. After some research i noticed that i should use the `system task-scheduler` instead of a cronjob. So i created an `ping.sh` file in `/config/scripts/`, set the permissions to `0755` and did an `chmod +x ping.sh`. This is the content of the `ping.sh` file (for test purposes)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ping Pong!"
echo "Ping Pong!!" >> result.txt
```

When i execute the script manually `./ping.sh` the script works fine, it echo's `Ping Pong!` and writes `Ping Pong!!` to `result.txt`. When i try to execute the script with the `system task-scheduler` it does nothing. I tried 2 task scheduler configurations and restarted the Edgerouter after `commit; save;`:

```
show system task-scheduler task
 task ping-task {
     crontab-spec "* *  *   *   *"
     executable {
         path /config/scripts/ping.sh
     }
 }
```

and

```
show system task-scheduler task
 task ping-task {
     executable {
         path /config/scripts/ping.sh
     }
     interval 1m
 }
```

What do i wrong? I checked multiple topics about it on https://community.ui.com/ but could not find a solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution seemed perfectly fine to me (running on a **EdgeRouter X v2.0.9-hotfix.1**).

I believe you just had some problem with relative paths or permissions when writing your `result.txt` file.

I did set an absolute path for `result.txt` (in `/tmp` directory) and it worked for me:

```bsh
cat > /config/scripts/pinger.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ping Pong!!" >> /tmp/result.txt
EOF

chmod +x /config/scripts/pinger.sh

configure
set system task-scheduler task pinger executable path /config/scripts/pinger.sh
set system task-scheduler task pinger interval 1m
commit ; save ; exit

watch cat /tmp/result.txt
```

With the last command you can see a line being added every 1 minute.